# Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s)

Tags: angular, typescript, msal-angular, msal

I am trying to import MsalModule in my app.module.ts, when importing it I get the following error:

```
Error: node_modules/@azure/msal-angular/msal.redirect.component.d.ts:14:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires 7 type argument(s).

14     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<MsalRedirectComponent, "app-redirect", never, {}, {}, never, never, false, never>;
```

The problem is that the msal.redirect.component file does not exist.

I also tried updating the dependencies but it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you give use the version of MSAL and the version of Angular you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error happens when the library you're using (here MSAL) requires a greater version of Angular that the one you're using.